# What chip is this? I suspect it's a CAN transceiver

Tags: identification, can, transceiver

I couldn't find this part number after googling.. both chips appear to say:

NXP
A42/3C
EVG000 (or EV0000)
nD921

but it's hard to read. Here's a pic below. I'm guessing they are the [NXP TJA1042](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/302/TJA1042-1127932.pdf), despite the differing part numbers because the full NXP part number is TJ**A**10**42**T/**3**/**C**M (emphasis mine.) Any other ideas?

[image]

Comment: TJA1042 are explicitly labelled "TJA1042". Also judging by the layout (hard to tell), it doesn't really look like a CAN transceiver. A better picture with less reflections and covering surrounding components would help.

Comment: Pin-3 could be VCC and Pin-2 could be GND. Judging from the image I can say that the chips share these lines. But why would a designer route CAN lines underneath the IC? CANL of the IC to the left and CANH of the IC to the right goes directly to the connector. Well, if these are really CAN xceivers then the routing shouldn't have been done like shown.

Comment: Good points! I'll try to take a better and more complete picture tomorrow in the daylight. This is a module for a car, and there are no other CAN transceivers on the board (or in the microcontroller like the LPC11Cxx family has.)

Comment: What kind of PCB is that/what is its function? the info might help us identify it.

Comment: @RohatKılıç  it looks like designer has the terminal pins in the wrong order for convenient wiring.

Comment: @RohatKılıç Also, why a decoupling cap on one IC supply but not the other. And there's this weird stub on the pin 2 trace on the right IC. Overall strange layout indeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a TJA1042 "single source" according to [this document](https://community.nxp.com/pwmxy87654/attachments/pwmxy87654/other/6248/1/Dual%20Source%20SSMC%20attachment%20PCN%20201301011F01.pdf).

[image]

Comment: So it's a part older than that PCN from 2013? Also... anyone else getting deadly tired of "we will not tell you the part marking in the actual datasheet because that would make the datasheet useful"?

Comment: @Lundin Yes, there should be an international package marking database.